# Is there a way to convert a graph network to a relational dataset in R?

Tags: r, networking, graph, relational

I have a dataset that consists of linked nodes, that I'm trying to convert to a simple relational table. The structure is like this:

```
Key1 Key2
A    A
A    B
A    C
B    A
B    B
B    C
C    A
C    B
C    C
D    D
D    E
E    D
E    E
F    F
```

At the end of the day, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way in R (outside of a loop, which would be too slow given the size of the set) to get every possible related values under a new unique master ID. The final dataset would like something like this:

```
Master   Key
1        A
1        B
1        C
2        D
2        E
3        F
```

I can't find anything on the topic because I'm likely asking the question without the proper terminology.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please elaborate on the mapping between your input and your desired output

Comment: you could use `components` from `igraph`

Comment: To elaborate on input to output:
Each combination of Key1 to Key2 is a group of IDs that are related. Each ID that is related is replicated on both sides of the dataframe. To put it another way, the number of rows in the dataframe containing the graph connections is always a square - since A, B, and C are connected, there are nine total rows in the dataframe. Since F is not connected to anything, there is only one. There are no keys that are partially connected.
I need to try and get each group of connected keys classified with a group number. I'm trying igraph now, with some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply getting the connected components of the graph.

Using your data:

```
Dat = read.table(text="Key1 Key2
A    A
A    B
A    C
B    A
B    B
B    C
C    A
C    B
C    C
D    D
D    E
E    D
E    E
F    F", 
header=TRUE)
```

We turn the edges into a graph and get the connected components.

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(Dat), directed=FALSE)
components(g)$membership
A B C D E F 
1 1 1 2 2 3
```

Note that `components(g)$membership` is a vector with named components. The A,B,C,D,E,F can be accessed with `names(components(g)$membership)`

Comment: Thank you for this! I couldn't get it working at first but then I realized that in my actual dataset, the letters are actually numbers, which were preventing the graph from generating properly. I converted them to character and everything works fine.